# Assertion error when comparing the text of an element

Tags: automated-testing, selenium2, java, assert

I am getting the following error while trying to verify an assertion. I tried adding wait, but it didn't help.

Error message:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: expected:<Risk Assessment Form: Completed> 
but was:<[[ChromeDriver: chrome on XP 
(73e81e18d39e6aaa89afd908b8438a82)] -> css selector: div.container-fluid > h3]>
```

The following is the code that I am writing:

```
 page2.selectCreateRiskAssessment();
 new WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(
              ExpectedConditions.presenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy(
              By.linkText("View Risk Assessment"))
 ); 
 assertEquals("Risk Assessment Form: Completed",
              driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.container-fluid > h3"))
 );
```

Answer (score 1):

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.container-fluid > h3"))
```

The findElement returns a WebElement and not its text and thus you cannot compare them like that.

WebElements have a function `getText()` to return the text of the object.

The assert should look like this:

```
assertEquals("Risk Assessment Form: Completed", 
             driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.container-fluid > h3")).getText());
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I was not able to figure out what was the issue and i didnt realize that i am not using .getText().  It is working fine now. Thanks.